# Get percentage variation of numbers from two dataframes based on column positioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data":(1,2,3)})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data":(2,4,6)})
```

I want to get the percentage variation numbers of the columns.

I have tried the below code:

```
data1_i=df1.set_index(["Product"])

data2_i=df2.set_index(["Product"])

data_diff=(data2_i-data1_i)/data1_i*100
data_diff.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output obtained:

```
    Product Data
0   A   100.0
1   B   100.0
2   C   100.0
```

I am able to do this since the column name are same. How to get the variation if I have different column names like below:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data":(1,2,3)})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data_new":(2,4,6)})
```

I wont be able to use rename functions as I have lot of columns. I want to get the variation on numbers based on **column positioning**. Any pointers so that I can get started

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select columns by position with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data":(1,2,3)})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product':("A","B","C"),"Data_new":(2,4,6)})
data1_i=df1.set_index(["Product"])
data2_i=df2.set_index(["Product"])

data_diff=(data2_i.iloc[:, 0]-data1_i.iloc[:, 0])/data1_i.iloc[:, 0]*100
data_diff = data_diff.reset_index(name='Data')
print (data_diff)
  Product   Data
0       A  100.0
1       B  100.0
2       C  100.0
```

Comment: @jezarel Thank you. But it works if you have variation of numbers for one column, in this scenario you are able to use reset_index.
It gives:TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame, if I have multiple columns

Comment: Then use `data_diff = data_diff.reset_index()`, `data_diff = data_diff.reset_index(name='Data')` working only with one column